# raw_input_wrapper() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given Python 3.5

Tags: python

I am trying to make a text based adventure game and I am getting this error: "0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given."  I am not sure what it means or how to fix it.  Could someone explain the problem to me?  Thank you!

```
##########################################################
##farm game
##########################################################


player_name =  input("What's your name? ")
print ("Hello {}".format(player_name))

print ("You wake up to the sound of your mother calling from the kitchen: 
       {}" .format(player_name), ", wake up!  I need your help in the kitchen!")
ch1 = str(input("Will you go downstairs? "))

# kitchen
if ch1 in ['y', 'Y', 'Yes', 'YES', 'yes']:
    print("You go downstairs.")
    ch2 = str(input("Your mother is in front of the oven, preparing to make 
                 a loaf of bread.  She turns to look at you and says: {}" 
                .format(player_name), ", I need three eggs.  Please go fetch 
                 the eggs from the barn."))
if ch2 in ['y', 'Y', 'Yes', 'YES', 'yes']:
    print("You leave the kitchen and enter the large back yard.  You are in 
       a fenced in area.  Three pigs are rooting around in the fresh spring 
       grass, snorting and snuffling.  At the end of the yard is the barn, 
       where the cows and horses live.  To your right is the kitchen coop.  
       You can hear the soft clucking of chickens from inside.")

# no kitchen
else:
    print("You look around the room.")
```

Comment: My if and print statements are indented, but I did not copy paste it like that here.  So I don't think it is a syntax issue.

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing too many arguments into `input()`. See the following examples:

```
>>> x = input()
hello world
>>> print(x)
hello world


>>> x = input("Say hello: ")
Say hello: hello world
>>> print(x)
hello world


>>> x = input("first argument", "second argument")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

To add the player name to your input, move the `.format` to the end of the string:

```
ch2 = input("Your mother is in front of the oven, preparing to make a loaf of bread.  She turns to look at you and says: {} , I need three eggs. Please go fetch the eggs from the barn.".format(player_name)))
```

Comment: That fixed the problem!  Thank you.